# How can I test my iPhone app on earlier than SDK 3.0 simulator, make sure it work?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I wrote iPhone application. Very simple! It use Cocos2D only, and all other features is very basic, no accelerometer, no camera, nothing. Just buttons and sounds.

I think every iPhone can run this app (there is no limits on Cocos2D right?), but my XCode only let me use 3.0 and upwards. I want to confirm 1 thing and ask one thing:

1. If I put "iPhone OS 2.0" in my iPhone OS Deployment Target in XCode, but my "Active SDK" in XCode still says 3.0, if I compile using this and submit to App Store, when it goes up, people who use 2.0 can still download and use the game yes?
2. Is there way I can test in a 2.0 simulator to make sure it works? My XCode only have 3.0 and higher simulation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set your Deployment Target for iPhone OS 2.0 and Base SDK for whatever version of the SDK you have (3.0, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.2, etc.). Active SDK is just a compile-time override of the Base SDK. You should set your Base SDK to the latest **STABLE** version of the SDK and the Deployment to the oldest device you intend to support.
2. If you open up the iPhone Simulator and select from the menu bar Hardware > Version, you should see an option for SDK version 2.x. If you don't see this, you don't have any 2.0 SDK versions installed. 2.2.1 was included up to version 3.1.3, but you might not see it in the Simulator. You'll have to find an older version of the SDK to install. They can be found online by Googling. Don't have a link off-hand, but shouldn't be hard.

***Edit***

This is out-of-date for the newest version of Xcode (currently 3.2.5).